# Found nil in flickrSearchURLForSearchTerm

Tags: ios, swift, flickr

Seems to me that I found good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started) about instruments from Ray Wenderlich but it is for Xcode 6+ and iOS 8+ so there were some issues that had to change.

After I changed the code I don't have any errors but one morning about scene that is unreachable. But when I run the app and try to find some "Cats" in Flickr I had "Found nil" in the last line of the following code:

```
//
//  FlickrSearcher.swift
//  flickrSearch
//
//  Created by Richard Turton on 31/07/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Razeware. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

let apiKey = "a3764131ee7cca9d9591c5ad5490b325"

struct FlickrSearchResults {
  let searchTerm : String
  let searchResults : [FlickrPhoto]
}

class FlickrPhoto : Equatable {
  let photoID : String
  let title: String
  private let farm : Int
  private let server : String
  private let secret : String

  typealias ImageLoadCompletion = (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void

  init (photoID:String, title:String, farm:Int, server:String, secret:String) {
    self.photoID = photoID
    self.title = title
    self.farm = farm
    self.server = server
    self.secret = secret
  }

  func flickrImageURL(size:String = "m") -> NSURL {
    return NSURL(string: "http://farm\(farm).staticflickr.com/\(server)/\(photoID)_\(secret)_\(size).jpg")!
  }

  func loadThumbnail(completion: ImageLoadCompletion) {
    loadImageFromURL(URL: flickrImageURL("m")) { image, error in
      completion(image: image, error: error)
    }
  }

  func loadLargeImage(completion: ImageLoadCompletion) {
    loadImageFromURL(URL: flickrImageURL("b"), completion: completion)
  }

  func loadImageFromURL(URL URL: NSURL, completion: ImageLoadCompletion) {
    let loadRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(loadRequest,
      queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        response, data, error in

        if error != nil {
          completion(image: nil, error: error)
          return
        }

        if data != nil {
          completion(image: UIImage(data: data!), error: nil)
          return
        }

        completion(image: nil, error: nil)
    }
  }
}


extension FlickrPhoto {
  var isFavourite: Bool {
    get {
      return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(photoID)
    }
    set {
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: photoID)
    }
  }
}

func == (lhs: FlickrPhoto, rhs: FlickrPhoto) -> Bool {
  return lhs.photoID == rhs.photoID
}

class Flickr {

  let processingQueue = NSOperationQueue()

  func searchFlickrForTerm(searchTerm: String, completion : (results: FlickrSearchResults?, error : NSError?) -> Void){

    let searchURL = flickrSearchURLForSearchTerm(searchTerm)
    let searchRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: searchURL)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(searchRequest, queue: processingQueue) {response, data, error in
      if error != nil {
        completion(results: nil,error: error)
        return
      }

      var resultsDictionary = NSDictionary()
      print("\(resultsDictionary) resultsDic created")

      do {
        resultsDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as! NSDictionary
        print(resultsDictionary.count)
      } catch let JSONError as NSError {
        completion(results: nil, error: JSONError)
        print(JSONError)
        return

      }

      switch (resultsDictionary["stat"] as! String) {
      case "ok":
        print("Results processed OK")
      case "fail":
        let APIError = NSError(domain: "FlickrSearch", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey:resultsDictionary["message"]!])
        completion(results: nil, error: APIError)
        return
      default:
        let APIError = NSError(domain: "FlickrSearch", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey:"Unknown API response"])
        completion(results: nil, error: APIError)
        return
      }

      let photosContainer = resultsDictionary["photos"] as! NSDictionary
      let photosReceived = photosContainer["photo"] as! [NSDictionary]

      let flickrPhotos : [FlickrPhoto] = photosReceived.map {
        photoDictionary in

        let photoID = photoDictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let title = photoDictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
        let farm = photoDictionary["farm"] as? Int ?? 0
        let server = photoDictionary["server"] as? String ?? ""
        let secret = photoDictionary["secret"] as? String ?? ""

        let flickrPhoto = FlickrPhoto(photoID: photoID, title: title, farm: farm, server: server, secret: secret)

        return flickrPhoto
      }

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        completion(results:FlickrSearchResults(searchTerm: searchTerm, searchResults: flickrPhotos), error: nil)
      })
    }
  }

  private func flickrSearchURLForSearchTerm(searchTerm:String) -> NSURL {

    let escapedTerm = searchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

    let URLString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=\(apiKey)&text=\(escapedTerm)&per_page=20&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
    return NSURL(string: URLString)! // error line
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]
What here is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake!
You should unwrap the optional so last method should be like this:

```
private func flickrSearchURLForSearchTerm(searchTerm:String) -> NSURL {

    let escapedTerm = searchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

    let URLString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=\(apiKey)&text=\(escapedTerm)&per_page=20&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
    print(URLString)
    return NSURL(string: URLString)!
  }
```

After that should allow transport security in info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict>
```

After that it works pretty fine!
Hope someone will use it!